# Access the field that is a nested array inside JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON format. I need to access the text in the "See" field which is present in "highlighting" field. Please let me know how do I access it using jquery. Help is appreciated.

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
            "QTime": 61,
            "params": {
            "df": "See",
                "indent": "true",
                "q": "boating\n",
                "hl.simple.pre": "<em>",
                "hl.simple.post": "</em>",
                "wt": "json",
                "hl": "true"
        }
    },
        "response": {
        "numFound": 28,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [{
            "id": "26204",
                "title": "Osoyoos",
                "Getin": "\nGet in\n\n\nOsoyoos is in the south central interior of British Columbia, approximately 400nbsp;km east of Vancouver at the junction of Highways 97 and 3 near the border of Washington State. ",
                "Other": "ootenays.\n\n\n\nWikipedia\nOsoyoos, British Columbia\n\n\n\n\n",
                "Understand": "asant weather in April. Current weather conditions and historical climate data can be found online at Environment Canada . \n\n",
                "See": "boating and fishing. Lakeside campsites and privacy make this a popular camping area.  Reservations are necessary during the summer months, call\n1-800-689-9025.\n\n",
                "_version_": 1453197586830721000
        }]
    },
        "highlighting": {
        "112855": {
            "See": [
                "<em>Boating</em>, Swimming,  Fishing - <em>Boating</em>, swimming,  Fishing in Melamadai Vandiyur Lake provides some"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `YourVariable.highlighting.112855.See`, Here `See` is an array. You can use index to access its element

Answer (score 0):

suppose you decode the JSON string you posted into the variable **jsonDecodedObj**

```
jsonDecodedObj = $.parseJSON( jsonEncodedString )
```

you can access **See** this way

```
see = jsonDecodedObj['highlighting']['112855']['See'][0];
```

Note that "See" is an array containing just one object (thus the final [0]).

**But** in case the key '112855' (that presumabily is the id of the highlighted item) is subject to change from response to response you may capture **See** in the followinf way

```
jsonDecodedObj = $.parseJSON( jsonEncodedString )

highlighting = jsonDecodedObj.highlighting;

for( obj in highlighting ) {
    See = highlighting[obj].See[0];
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend with the name of your variable:

```
highlighting[112855].See
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this will work

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
"responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
        "QTime": 61,
        "params": {
        "df": "See",
            "indent": "true",
            "q": "boating\n",
            "hl.simple.pre": "<em>",
            "hl.simple.post": "</em>",
            "wt": "json",
            "hl": "true"
    }
},
    "response": {
    "numFound": 28,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
        "id": "26204",
            "title": "Osoyoos",
            "Getin": "\nGet in\n\n\nOsoyoos is in the south central interior of British Columbia, approximately 400nbsp;km east of Vancouver at the junction of Highways 97 and 3 near the border of Washington State. ",
            "Other": "ootenays.\n\n\n\nWikipedia\nOsoyoos, British Columbia\n\n\n\n\n",
            "Understand": "asant weather in April. Current weather conditions and historical climate data can be found online at Environment Canada . \n\n",
            "See": "boating and fishing. Lakeside campsites and privacy make this a popular camping area.  Reservations are necessary during the summer months, call\n1-800-689-9025.\n\n",
            "_version_": 1453197586830721000
    }]
},
    "highlighting": {
    "112855": {
        "See": [
            "<em>Boating</em>, Swimming,  Fishing - <em>Boating</em>, swimming,  Fishing in Melamadai Vandiyur Lake provides some"]
    }
}
})

var parse = JSON.parse(data)


console.log(parse.highlighting[112855].See )
```

Will give this result

```
["<em>Boating</em>, Swimming,  Fishing - <em>Boating</em>, swimming,  Fishing in Melamadai Vandiyur Lake provides some"]
```